# intl extension to use CakePHP not working

Tags: xampp, cakephp-3.0

> Fatal error: You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\config\bootstrap.php on line 38

I have already Change `;extension=php_intl.dll` to `extension=php_intl.dll` (remove the semicolon) in php.ini
and restart the server through the XAMPP Control Panel.

same error comes.

This is my error log displaying in XAMPP

> [22-Feb-2016 14:24:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
>   dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_intl.dll' - The specified module
>   could not be found. in Unknown on line 0

please  tell how to resolved this issue

I read this instruction
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#requirements

Comment: Have you checked whether the file actually exists (the error is typical for non-existent/accessible files)? And if it exists, make sure that it's compatible with (compiled for) the PHP version that you are using.

Comment: I updated xampp now my problem solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, however, I was actually developing on a Linux box locally. However, what'ever version of XAMPP you're running, basically does not have the module installed or enabled.

You might go looking for that "line to uncomment", but sadly it won't be there. This means you need to install that module.

Not sure how to do that for XAMPP, however, I'm sure you can Google how to install the package!

#################### IF YOUR ON YOUR OWN LINUX BOX

just run this

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

Why php5? Well it's what I have installed, so if you're running greater than that in the future, just adjust php5 to phpx whatever you're running there!